# How to fix Failed to deploy VM: postNFCData failed:H

Tags: vmware-esxi, cisco

I am doing networking stuff after 20 years.  I don't remember a lot. So please help.

We have a ESXi server with the following capacity:

[image: ESXi]

[image: Host info]

Basically, we need to import the Cisco Firepower Management Center (FMC) and the Cisco Firepower Threat Defense (FTD). We uploaded the .OVF file and the .VMDK which results in this error:

[image: ESXi error]

Googling, I found [this link](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-vSphere-Discussions/Resolve-Failed-to-Deploy-OVA-OVF-Issue-PostNFCdata-Failed/td-p/2741198): which just asks to change the capacity and has some way of calculation the needed one.

I have this excerpt from the OVF file:

```
<DiskSection>
  <Info>Virtual disk information</Info>
  <Disk ovf:capacity="250" ovf:capacityAllocationUnits="byte * 2^30" ovf:diskId="vmdisk1" ovf:fileRef="file1" ovf:format="http://www.vmware.com/interfaces/specifications/vmdk.html#streamOptimized" ovf:populatedSize="5428740096"/>
</DiskSection>
```

I tried different values of 200, 500 etc. I am unable to figure out how to arrive at the right number.  Whatever I do, I get the same above error. I will greatly appreciate if someone can help.